# Visual Studio on Production

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-server-2008

Does Visual Studio need to be installed on a production server?

My question is I need it to perform some task like (providers to connect to oracle for example) or only .net framework?

Answer (score 1):

You would need only the appropriate .NET framework version on the production server. Then you can deploy your code, which was developed in some internal server, to the production server.

Answer (score 1):

It's not needed at all. In fact, at most places I've seen Visual Studio is either implicitly or explicitly forbidden from production servers.

Apps that won't seem to run without VS having been installed usually just need some runtimes.